# 19.10: boot frozen on "/dev/sda2: clean, x/x files, x/x blocks"

Tags: boot

Ubuntu 19.10 boot frozen on "/dev/sda2: clean, x/x files, x/x blocks"

On boot my laptop freezes at the message in the title (with x as some number). I can access the command line with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>...<kbd>F6</kbd>

Prior to this, I had uninstalled python with:
`sudo apt remove python python3 python 3.8`

I reinstalled all those packages with:

`sudo apt install python python3 python3.8`

once this error occurred, but it still persisted.

With <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, I can login to a screen with this message:

> debugfs: File 'Codec' in directory 'System PCM' already present!

Would really appreciate help with this!

Comment: Please repeat title information in your question text (depending on browser used; heading may not be visible when reading your question text). The `fsck` messages just mean the system was rebooted 30 times and it was scheduled (or whatever value it was set to if not default) OR the system was uncleanly shutdown in the prior session thus `fsck` was performed & 'clean' is the positive result of a `fsck`.  Reinstalled it?  you removed multiple packages so does 'it' refer to just one, all? or something else?  I'd suggest clean shutdowns wherever possible, eg. sysrq, commands etc to sync, umount...

Comment: Edited the post to reflect new information, thanks! Do you have any suggestions on what to do next?